# VHDL: How to check selected bits of a vector

Tags: vhdl, boolean-logic, bitvector

I'm wondering if there is a way to check only the bits I'm interested in of an *std logic* vector in VHDL. My newest attempt looks like this:

```
IF (vectorname = "1-00") THEN

action

END IF;
```

I am here only interested to check the bits 3, 1 and 0 of the vector. Bit 2 is in this case irrelevant. I thought a `-` would work since it's "don't care", but it doesn't.

Any ways to do this simply? I know it's possible with `STD_MATCH`, but I want to take a different approach.

Comment: `if (vectorname(3)='1' and vectorname(1 downto 0) = "00) then`  Good questions, never though about a better way to code that.  I'm looking forward to see other solutions.

Comment: Could it be with VHDL-2008 and the '?=' operator is should work with the '-'?  But then, it could work in the simulator but if the synthesis tool is not as far in 2008, you blocked again.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `std_match`?  That's the "right" way to do it IMHO and I can't immediately think of a reason to "take a different approach"...

Answer (score 0):

First way (also answered by vermaete as a comment):

```
IF vectorname(3) = '1' AND vectorname(1 DOWNTO 0) = "00" THEN
  action
END IF;
```

...the above works if it's inside a process. If not, use something like this:

```
my_output <= "11111111" WHEN vectorname(3) = '1' AND vectorname(1 DOWNTO 0) = "00" ELSE "00000000";
```

Second way:

```
SIGNAL bits_i_care_about : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);


bits_i_care_about <= vectorname(3) & vectorname(1 DOWNTO 0);

p_my_process : PROCESS(bits_i_care_about)
BEGIN
  IF bits_i_care_about = "100" THEN
    action
  END IF;
END PROCESS;
```